# Retrieving and inserting data into a dialog message

Tags: android, dialog

I want to get the names from the ""Enter Recipicient" field once the "Message" field is clicked and placed into a "name" placeholder in the .setMessage of a dialog box. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from "Enter Recipicient" field. Here is some code.

```
 Button messagebtn;
    messagebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   String recName=recipicientEdittext.getText().toString();

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(recName);
                builder.setTitle("Your Title");
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                AlertDialog alertdialog = builder.create();
                alertdialog.show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!